# Hierarichal objects to Oracle stored procedure

Tags: c#

Below is my DTO structure

```
public class Config_DTO
{
    public string NAME { get; set; }
    public string TITLE { get; set; }
    public string TYP { get; set; }
    public string RMKS { get; set; }
    public string PROC { get; set; }
    public string ORGL_USER { get; set; }
    public DateTime ORGL_STAMP { get; set; }
    public string UPDT_USER { get; set; }
    public DateTime UPDT_STAMP { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<CommonConfig_DTO> COLUMNS_DATATYPE { get; set; }
}

public class CommonConfig_DTO
{
    public string COLUMNS { get; set; }
    public string DATA_TYP { get; set; }
}
```

How to pass these values to a backend procedure? I have tried converting this `<CommonConfig_DTO>` `COLUMNS_DATATYPE` to array, but I am not successful.